# Error : C1083 Cannot Open Compiler generated file : Permission denied ( VC++2015 )

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I am upgrading My VC++ MFC project from 2006 to 2015 , Now I am getting a error This error said cannot open compiler generate file ; Permission denied.
I am checking the project properties allow full control , and also allow read write data. but its also not working .
Please Help me (:

1. Trying clean and build project not working
2. Give full path in configuration Properties not working .
3. Allow full control to project file not working .

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Your first step should be googling error code: `C1083` then you would find full instruction: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/fatal-error-c1083?view=msvc-170

Comment: Precompiled header file generation isn't properly set up. You have to adjust the `/Yc` and `/Yu` compiler options accordingly. See [Precompiled Header Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/creating-precompiled-header-files) for details. Alternatively, don't make use of precompiled header files altogether.

Comment: Yeh, now its working changing Precompiled header file /Yu to /Yc.. Thank